# how to change color of column in html table using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
    var tr = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var first_td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
        first_td.onmouseover = function () {
            hover('on');
        }
        first_td.onmouseout = function () {
            hover('off');
        }
    }
    function hover(state) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var first_td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
            if (state == 'on') {
                first_td.style.color = 'White';
                first_td.style.background = 'RED';
            }
            else if (state == 'off') {
                first_td.style.color = '#000';
                first_td.style.background = '#fff';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do this but this code not working for all table column. in this code there only any one column are worked. other column are not working. please provide the code for the change all the column change color on hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are explicitly taking first column element only.replace your script  with

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');

    var tr = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var tdlist=tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for(var j=0; j<tdlist.length; j++)
        {
            var first_td = tdlist[j];
            first_td.onmouseover = function () {
               hover(this,'on');
            }
             first_td.onmouseout = function () {
               hover(this,'off');
             }
        }
    }
    function hover(obj,state) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            var first_td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[obj.cellIndex];
            if (state == 'on') {
                first_td.style.color = 'White';
                first_td.style.background = 'RED';
            }
            else if (state == 'off') {
                first_td.style.color = '#000';
                first_td.style.background = '#fff';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not correct. i want to change column color on mouse hover. For ex, i have 3 X 3, table. like R0C0, R1C0, R2C0 this is 1st column. R0C1, R1C1, R2C1 2nd column & R0C2, R1C2, R2C2 this 3rd column. if i mouse hove on "C0" column mean 1st column all the C0 column change the color & like all the column.

Comment: <table border="1" style="width: 50%" id="TABLE" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>R0C0</td>
                    <td>R0C1</td>
                    <td>R0C2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>R1C0</td>
                    <td>R1C1</td>   
                    <td>R1C2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>R2C0</td>
                    <td>R2C1</td>   
                    <td>R2C2</td>
                </tr>

Comment: Hi @Deva I have modified my answer based on your discussion, Please use this script. However you can use mouseover function on <td> element to achieve this

Comment: @Deva Please let me know if it worked for you or not

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly grab only the first cell here:

```
var first_td=tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
```

The getElementsByTagName call returns a list of all the td elements, instead of just indexing the first one you will need to loop through the list (as you do with the list of tr's) and set each ones style.

This seems pretty inefficient however - you might want to consider doing this with CSS instead. See this code snippet for an example using CSS:

```css
table {

  border-collapse: collapse;

}

table,

th,

td {

  border: 1px solid black;

}

td {

  padding: 0.5em 1em;

}

td:hover {

  color: white;

  background: blue;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>One One</td>
        <td>Two One</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One One</td>
        <td>Two One</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```